How to add an aria-label attribute to a custom angular component?
I want to add an aria-label attribute to an external Angular component (<code-input>), as shown below:
<code-input [isCodeHidden]="true" [code-length]="2" [attr.aria-label]="Test">

I attempted to add the aria-label using the [attr.aria-label] attribute and aria-labelledby. However, when I inspect the page with the EqualWeb accessibility checker tool, I receive errors indicating that the <code-input> component is missing an aria-label for the input fields.
The <code-input> component captures user input, such as a PIN. Given a code-length of 2, it renders two input boxes.
Expected Outcome: The custom Angular component should render two input boxes with the aria-label applied to each input field individually. Upon inspecting the component with the EqualWeb accessibility checker tool, there should be no AODA compliance errors.
Actual Outcome: The aria-label is applied only to the outer HTML block of the <code-input> component. The individual input boxes within the component do not have the aria-label attribute, resulting in AODA compliance errors when inspected.
The code-input component is part of an external dependency, so I cannot modify it directly. I need to use the component and set the [code-length] property. How can I ensure that the aria-label attribute is applied to each input element? For example, if [code-length] is set to 2, aria-label should be applied to two input elements, and if [code-length] is set to 4, aria-label should be applied to four input elements
How can I apply the aria-label attribute to each input field within a custom Angular component like <code-input>?

Can you change the code-input component or does it come from an external dependency? Looks like it might be https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-code-input

I found a GitHub issue which addresses some accessibility issues: https://github.com/AlexMiniApps/angular-code-input/issues/103 Unfortunately, in Angular there is no build-in way for adding extra attributes to the internal elements of an external component. However you can use JavaScript DOM manipulation to add the attributes.

[attr.aria-something]="value" or attr.aria-something="string-with-{{interpolation}}" should work

if code-input is your component then instead of trying to attach the aria label here you can pass it an input to the component and bind it inside the component definition.

@JSONDerulo Yes, code-input is external component.

"Windicating that the  component is missing an aria-label for the input fields."
You only add the [attr.aria-label]="Test" to your component, not to the "inputs" inside the components.

If your "aria-label" is fixed, in parent
   <component aria-label="test"/>

As is an attribute you can use in constructor
constructor(@Optional() @Attribute('arial-label') public ariaLabel){}

And in the .html of the component in each inputs
<input [attr.arial-label]="ariaLabel"/>


If you can "change" the attribute, you need use an Input instead of
get the value in the constructor
In parent
<component [ariaLabel]="name"/>

In your component
ariaLabel=input();

and the .html
<input [attr.aria-label]="ariaLabel()"/>



both examples in this stackblitz
Update If we can not access to the input we need use javascript.
We inject the elementRef in constructor, and use getElementsByTagName to "reach" the inputs.
export class Child3 implements AfterViewInit {
  name = 'Angular';
  ariaLabel = input<string>('');
  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    [...this.el.nativeElement.getElementsByTagName('input')].forEach(
      (x: HTMLElement) => x.setAttribute('aria-label', this.ariaLabel())
    );
  }
}


Thank you for the explanation ! I cannot modify the  element in my HTML template. All I can modify is the [code-length] property on the component .

@askbloopink, I update the answer. You need use pure javascript.
